# Google Analytics Embed API display charts of different pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I’m trying to display Google Analytics charts using the embed API with data that is being returned. I am currently returning the data from 3 different pages which works great. But is there a way of viewing that data in 3 separate charts?

This is the code that returns the results

```
var query = {
ids: VIEW_ID,
metrics: 'ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews,ga:sessions',
dimensions: 'ga:date,ga:pagePath',
filters: ‘ga:pagePath=@page1, ga:pagePath=@page2, ga:pagePath=@page3’ <!—page data returned
}

var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({ query });
report.on('success', function(response) {
  //console.log(response);
});

report.execute();
```

I then want to display 3 different charts using the embed API.  And switch between the charts using select> option elements.  At the minute the id is being passed through and displaying all accounts, properties, and views.

```
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
   container: 'view-selector-container'
});

// Render the view selector to the page.
      viewSelector.execute();


var chart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
query: {
    ids: VIEW_ID,
    dimensions: 'ga:date',
    metrics: 'ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews,ga:sessions',
    filters: ‘ga:pagePath=@page1, ga:pagePath=@page2, ga:pagePath=@page3’ <!—page data returned
},
chart: {
    type: 'LINE',
    container: 'line-chart',
    options: {
        fontSize: 12,
        width: '100%',
        colors: ['#4490BA', '#38A240', '#BD5065', '#BB8A21']
    }
}
});
chart.on('success', function(response) {           
});

viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
     chart.set({ query: { ids: VIEW_ID }}).execute();
});
```

The above returns every account, property and all website data.  I just want the data of the 3 different pages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to work it out myself.

I have my html elements which the charts get appended to from the Google script

```
<div id="line-chart-1"></div>
<div id="line-chart-2"></div>
<div id="line-chart-3"></div>
```

Then I created an array of where the page URLS get added to.  Then looped through the array X amount of times which generated, in this case, 3 different charts; one for each page.

```
var valueArray = ['page1-url', page2-url, 'page3-url'];

for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {

    var num = i + 1;

    var chart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
            ids: VIEW_ID,
            dimensions: 'ga:date',
            metrics: 'ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviews,ga:sessions',
                filters: valueArray[i]
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'LINE',
                container: 'line-chart-' + num,
                options: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    width: '100%',
                    colors: ['#4490BA', '#38A240', '#BD5065', '#BB8A21']
                }
            }
        });
        chart.on('success', function(response) {});
        chart.execute();
    }
```